# Run a command until it gets value in bash

Tags: linux, bash, openstack

How can I run a command until it gets value?

I want to spawn a vm-s in openstack and I want to measure how many second it takes until the first ping is successful.

I have this command this will spawn a spawningtestlin machine:

```
nova boot --image "imagename" --flavor m2.large --nic net-id=87y38788 --availability-zone vlan:asd055 spawningtestlin
```

after I want to get the ip of the machine with this command:

```
machineip=$(nova list --name spawningtestlin|grep spawningtestlin|awk -F= '{print $2}'|awk '{print $1}'|sed 's/ //g')
```

The problem is it takes some time to get the ip so the machineip value many times empty, however the return code is 0. So I want the script continue only if this has value.

And after would come this until the first ping arrives:

```
until ping -c1 $machineip &>/dev/null; do :; done
```

And this would be the script and I would measure it with the time command when I run the script.

How is it possible?

Any idea welcome, can change everything just make it work :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the script finally, I had to use the until and it works:

```
> /var/tmp/machineip
touch /var/tmp/machineip
nova boot --image "ewefewf" --flavor m2.large --nic net-id=wefewf --availability-zone LA2:s55 spawningtestwin

until grep "1" /var/tmp/machineip > /dev/null;
do
    nova list --name spawningtestwin|grep spawningtestwin|awk -F= '{print $2}'|awk '{print $1}'|sed 's/ //g' > /var/tmp/machineip
done

mip=$(cat /var/tmp/machineip)
until ping -c1 $mip &>/dev/null; do :; done

end=`date +%s`
runtime=$((end-start))
echo $runtime
```